# get the values from table where the column value is not equal to zero

Tags: php, mysql

i have one maildigest column in my users table so..when user logged in i keep the value in session like this

```
$_SESSION['maildigest'] = $user->maildigest;
```

so what happened is for some particular records this column value is zero..and some particular records this column value is there like 143,113

so i am tying to show the records where the maildigest column not equal to zero in this query

i keep the session value in one variable

```
$parentclientadmin=$_SESSION['maildigest'];

$retval = "SELECT * FROM `mdl_user`  where  maildigest IN ($id,$parentclientadmin) and trackforums='1' ";
```

can anyone help me i want to get records where maildigest not equal to zero

thanks in advance...

Comment: did you try to compare session value is zero or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!=` there:-

```
$retval = "SELECT * FROM `mdl_user`  WHERE  maildigest IN ($id,$parentclientadmin) AND trackforums='1' AND maildigest !=0";
```

NOTE:-  try to use `prepared`statements to prevent from `SQL Injection`.

Comment: hi i have one doubt?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Prepared Statement instead and your `SQL` should be

```
SELECT * FROM `mdl_user`  where  trackforums='1' and maildigest != ?";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using <> instead of !=

```
$retval = "SELECT * FROM `mdl_user`  where  maildigest <> 0 ";
```

<> is the variant present in the SQL ISO standard.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could do it this way

```
$retval = "SELECT * FROM `mdl_user`  where  maildigest!=0 ";
```